# overlay images over another and keep both of them in the background

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 2 images that i need to use one over another while keeping them in the background, 
currently i used the following code :

```
<div id="about_splash">
<img style="width:85%" src="image_src" />
</div>
```

where about_splash has the background css attribute

The problem is, these 2 images need to be in the background of some other html objects. which would be above and below div#about_splash.

I tried putting z-index, but that didnt work.

If i use the following code, how can i scale the inner image so it is a bit bigger than the parent

```
    <div style="background: url(layout/images/illustration.gif) 
        no-repeat center;min-    height:500px;">

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Farhan Ahmad** already provided a good answer to you, however I'd like to contribute a bit further and maybe it would be of some help in the future.

This is a small code snippet I used a while ago for positioning a container in **the dead center of the screen** and then positioning another container in the middle of the first one. The positioning is fluid and it depends on the resolution of the viewer.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parentContainer">
    <div id="childContainer">
       <!-- I'm the center of attention -->
    </div>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
#parentContainer
{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #9dc0dd;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px; /*This is half of the container Height*/
    margin-left: -100px; /*This is half of the container Width*/
}

#childContainer
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #435c68;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px; /*This is half of the container Height*/
    margin-left: -50px; /*This is half of the container Width*/
}​
```

A demo of the above snippet can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g2w7e/24/).

Comment: i this this did the trick for what i was looking for exactly. 
http://jsfiddle.net/g2w7e/41/

Comment: I'm still not sure what are you trying to achieve, because the Fiddle you provided hints that your idea might be different. There might be a more elegant solution to your case, but as I said, I'm still not sure what it is exactly.

Normally, in the snippet I provided you will have to put your content inside it so that it's positioned in the middle. Alternatively, I'm sure it can be done with what Farhan suggested.

Comment: basically, the basic need is to have a background image that is an overlay between 2 divs or list elements. http://jsfiddle.net/g2w7e/64/ ( just check the output, to see what i [link]want ). Now the problem is that the image between them is quite big(in size), so i needed to break it in 2 layers, that way they are reduced to 20% of the actual size. i'll try to get something out of this in the morning.. i think i got a clue of what i need to do, i'll post what i do, for comments..

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** CSS3 allows this sort of thing and it looks like this:

```
body {
    background-image: url(images/bg.png), url(images/bgtop.png);
    background-repeat: repeat, repeat-x;
}
```

However if you need to support IE8 or below, then the best way you can work around it is to have extra divs:

```
<body>
    <div id="bgTopDiv">
        content here
    </div>
</body>

body{
    background-image: url(images/bg.png);
}
#bgTopDiv{
    background-image: url(images/bgTop.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: the problem is not with the images, the thing is, i need the two images to act as a background.

Comment: thaanks for the answer, this seems pretty neat, by the way, i just realized my main problem was just that i wasnt using z-index, with position: absolute.. that solved the issue.. but this is relatively simpler as well.

Answer (score 1):

try looking at this also, http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp might give you more of an idea plus you can test at the bottom.

Thanks,
David

Comment: Please read this: http://w3fools.com . There are better resources. I was poisoned too by w3s long time ago :) , and took really hard time to remove bad habits.